# How would I set size limits to buckets on minio?

Tags: javascript, minio

I'm using minio on a VPS to host an S3 server. I'm making a cloud storage website as a personal project. I want every user to have a set amount of space, each user would have their own bucket. I already have most of the stuff set up, all I need is for the user to get a warning if their upload is over the capacity limit and cancel the file transfer.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/3846 for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set bucket quotas with the MinIO Client through `mc admin bucket quota`, for example  `mc admin bucket quota myminio/mybucket --hard 100GB`.

Note that quotas are lazily enforced, meaning it is possible for a period to go over quota.